# Are STL containers allowed to skip calling allocator::construct and allocator::destroy if the object is trivially constructible/destructible?

Tags: c++, allocator

The question is in the title. Is this allowed for containers, or are the allocator's methods guaranteed to be called even when the object is trivially constructible/destructible?

I did try to search for this but came back empty-handed... but if it's a duplicate please let me know.

Comment: It depends on if the container can detect that `allocator::construct` & `allocator::destroy` have trivial implementations. If these calls have some other effect besides simply constructing/destroying the object, they can't omit these calls.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: That's what I thought too, but then what was the point of introducing `is_trivially_destructible` and the others?

Comment: I think that containers are not allowed to skip it, but compilers may optimize it out (as inlining empty function).

Comment: @firda: Well in theory yeah, but in practice it turns out that inlining these to completely remove the loops is harder than it looks; it seems that aliasing prevents all of the instructions from getting removed. Also, from a complexity standpoint it should be something the caller can rely on.

Comment: @Mehrdad whether a type has a trivial destructor does have real consequences according to the Standard: for example, you're allowed to still access members of an object after destruction if the class has a trivial destructor; but if it's nontrivial then it's UB.

Comment: @Brian: Is that really why the type traits were introduced though? It sounds like a pretty niche use case...

Comment: STL containers may be well-known for the compiler and therefore it *can* be optimized to not call triviall destructors at all (because callint it or not calling have no observable difference).

Comment: @firda: It's not a question about the container, it's a question about the allocator. Even if the destructor is trivial, the allocator's implementation might be nontrivial, so the question is whether that permits the container to omit the call anyway.

Comment: As far as I know, every compiler with full optimization can optimize no-effect loops (compilers are good in one thing: they can repeat and repeat simple optimizations many times). I remember to write `for(volatile int counter = 10000; counter > 0; counter--);` to make my MCU wait for a while because without that `volatile` the whole loops disapears (nop = no operation).

Comment: The text is "For the components affected by this subclause that declare an `allocator_type`, objects stored in these components shall be constructed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct` function and
destroyed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy` function (20.7.8.2)". There's no provision allowing those calls to be omitted beyond the standard as-if rule.

Comment: @firda: I have code in *front* of me right now that doesn't do that in VC 2013, simply because there is a level of indirection involved with the iterators, defeating the compiler's optimizations. The aliasing analysis simply isn't as powerful as you imagine.

Comment: @T.C.: Feel free to post this as an answer! :) And perhaps also mention what the goal of introducing those type traits was?

Comment: Note about allocator: `allocator<T>::destroy(T* ptr) = ptr->~T()` which is empty and therefore it is same as my loop *without volatile*. In other words: it should get optimized-out (if no `volatile` is involved).

Comment: @firda: In the question, I'm talking about an arbitrary allocator, not `std::allocator`. The the loop I mentioned in my comment doesn't get optimized out even *with* `std::allocator`. (I know you're saying it "should", but I'm telling you it *doesn't*.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: full optimization? release mode? I am surprised really.

Comment: @firda: Sigh, yes, let me give you the counterexample... give me some time to make a small working one.

Comment: @firda: [Here's the counterexample](http://pastebin.com/E8bL215X), try it out yourself (MSVC 2013, 32-bit). It took me 5 minutes to code it; it's honestly not that hard to defeat the compiler, so please stop spreading the rumor that compilers are so smart nowadays. =P

Comment: @Mehrdad: A type's destructor can be trivial independent of the trivialness of some allocator's `destroy`. `is_trivially_destructible` only check a type's destructor. `is_trivially_destructible` cannot know about all of the hypothetical allocators which could potentially call a type's destructor.

Comment: Would there be any speed difference if you remove the inner code of the loop? `while (p->b != p->e) { alloc.destroy(p->b++); }` vs, `while (p->b != p->e) { *p->b++; }`? This actually involves *accessing* some memory, which can throw exception and thus may be problematic to optimize-out.

Comment: @firda: No, that's not the reason. I've already told you the likely cause. It has nothing to do with memory accesses throwing an exception; rather, it's almost certainly because of aliasing. To prove what I mean, allocate `P` on the stack (`P p(&arr[0], &arr[n])`, then change `p->` to `p.`).

Comment: @JaredHoberock: I'm not sure why you're telling me that, I'm already aware of that. That was the entire reason I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @firda: Since I took the time to write you the counterexample could you at least confirm that the loop isn't optimized out when you try the code?

Comment: @Mehrdad: g++ -O3 optimizes that out: http://pastebin.com/fMNhbhuz

Comment: @firda: I said **MSVC**. Can you confirm it behaves as I claimed on MSVC?

Comment: @Mehrdad: sure, I know, I wanted to try what I have on hand. MSVC is to blame, not STL :D (about MSVC - sorry, don't have MSVC 2013)

Comment: @firda: I'm not trying to assign blame here, I'm simply trying to prove to you that compilers aren't as smart as you think they are. I could probably defeat GCC too if I tried hard enough.

Comment: @firda: [**Here's proof**](http://ideone.com/tvwIyB) to you that GCC (and probably every compiler on the planet) still sucks at optimization. I hope this convinces you that you can't reply on *any* compiler to optimize away any nontrivial code.

Comment: Using ideone with whatever compiler using whatever settings proofs that all compilers sucks? No, I gave you the proof already that GCC optimized your loop to simple `if`, nothink else was left from the loop with full optimization on. So, I was believing you that MSVC is no good, but now think you are in debug mode :-D

Comment: @firda: Uh, did you actually *try* [the new code I gave you](http://ideone.com/tvwIyB) on your *own* compiler? It fails on *every* compiler I tried -- Clang, MSVC, and GCC.

Comment: @firda: Again, I'd appreciate it if you could please take a few seconds to try it out and let me know if my last counterexample works for you.

Comment: I'll try to compile and disassemble that later. Don't have time now.

Comment: @firda: Okay sure, let me know how it goes when you have, thanks.

Comment: @Mehrdad: did you change the code? I swear I have seen different code under your 'Here's proof' link (that was similar to the first one, except the starting argc math). Now I see something else (with `delete[] arr` and few ms more)

Comment: @firda: Yeah I have, sorry. I've revised it a bunch of times to make sure it's foolproof and not something I overlooked (e.g. I didn't have the `delete` originally, and I wasn't sure if that made a difference in terms of well-defined side effects... then I double-`delete`d by accident, so I fixed that too, etc.)... I think it's good now, but if you notice a valid reason for why it can't be optimized then let me know.

Comment: BTW: Is there a common place to move our conversation? We are poluting comments here. I am thinking about posting 'answer-like' reply here with results (when I have them), because it is 'related', but not the answer for the original question. ...and to be honest, I hate those downvotes when somebody things my answer 'is not answering the question' (I prefer to search for reasoning and provide unexpected answers to real problems behind the question - people often don't know how to ask and what to request because solution may be surprising).

Comment: @Mehrdad: I have compiled your code in VS2012 and decompiled using IDA (Hex-Rays) and found that the nontrivial destructor `~T() { ++x; }` gets called. Well, this proves one thing: there are cases when compiler is unable to detect that some code has no real effect. But this is far from the original question - nontrivial destructor on heap-allocated object. We were talking about trivial destructor with stack-allocated iterator. That is huge difference. (I can imagine why compiler does not understand that calling free/delete discards object state and this can be but is not optimized out.)

Comment: @firda: Regarding moving our conversation: yeah, we can take it to chat, but I'm not a big fan of it because I want others to be able to see the discussion too (no one's going to read the chat log, and someone's bound to repeat what you said). Regarding the trivial destructor: no; actually, [**you** were the one who said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127204), *"As far as I know, every compiler with full optimization can optimize no-effect loops."* So I was just trying to tell you that's wrong -- compilers aren't as smart as you think.

Comment: @Mehrdad: This cannot be considered no-effect loop, because you are changing state of object which you then pass to function (free) which can have whatever checks (and in debug has). You are making assumtion about free/delete (to have no effect and therefore any code changing the state of deleted object to have no real effect), but that assumption may not be true.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'll try to explain it once more: free is external function (cannot be inlined, it calls some `extern "C" _my_heap_free(void*)`) and that is why the compiler cannot see that the state of the object is irrelevant and therefore cannot optimize your nontrivial destructor out.

Comment: @firda: Have you even [tried ***not*** freeing the memory](http://ideone.com/RreXWY) before claiming that's the problem?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I have deleted my comment when I got what you mean, sorry. Will try new code.

Comment: @firda: It's ok. Now here's the kicker: you don't even need *any* heap allocation or external function whatsoever to defeat the optimizer. [Here's one that defeats Clang (but not GCC)](http://pastebin.com/44zpU5LM).

Comment: @Mehrdad: 'not freeing the memory' not optimized by VS2012, changing state of heap-allocated obect (yes, this is aliasing problem). Not suprised so much, but I would be really surprised if you can create unoptimized example for your original question (involving stack-allocated iterators with all-inlinable code and trivial destructor which would render your question as apropriate).

Comment: @firda: I don't understand what you mean about trivial destructors, it doesn't make any sense. If the destructor was trivial, **there would be *no destructor* to inline in the first place!** The *whole point* of the discussion about inlining is based on the assumption that there **is** a (hopefully side-effect-free) destructor to inline. How can you claim the compiler is inlining code that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Mehrdad: trivial (nonexistent) or empty (no real code, e.g. return only). VC optimizes your loop with empty constructor but not the one with destructor (changing state of heap-allocated object = again, aliasing problem). I was refering to your original question - allocator::destroy called by container on objects with trivial (or empty) destructor. I still think that this will get optimized-out (by good inlining - the same way your `for(int j=0;j<N;++j) new(&arr[j]) T()` disapeared form machine code).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58676/discussion-between-mehrdad-and-firda).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

§ 23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]/p3:

> For the components affected by this subclause that declare an
>   `allocator_type`, objects stored in these components shall be
>   constructed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct`
>   function and destroyed using the
>   `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy` function (20.7.8.2).

There's no provision allowing for those calls to be omitted beyond the as-if rule. In fact, I can't find a single instance of the word "trivial" in Clause 23, which specifies the standard library containers.

As to why they specified type traits like `is_trivially_destructible`, you'll have to dig out the original proposal paper for the rationale. It's not used in the C++14 standard, but it is currently [used to specify `std::optional`](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4078.html) in the draft Library Fundamentals TS:

> ```
> ~optional();
> ```
>
> - *Effects*: If `is_trivially_destructible<T>::value != true` and `*this` contains a value, calls `val->T::~T()`.
> - *Remarks*: If `is_trivially_destructible<T>::value == true` then this destructor shall be a trivial destructor.

Comment: This makes sense: allocator is here for some reason, it can be custom-made for whatever purpose. no constrain about T can be used not to call construct, destroy. Compiler is to optimize (by inlining and inlining and removing empty code so long that no operation remains).

Comment: BTW: Where can I find the specification? I am using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ and http://en.cppreference.com/w/ now.

Comment: @firda The most recent publicly available working draft is [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf). I believe you can dig out N3936, which is identical to the final draft for C++14, in the history of the [github repository](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) for draft standards.